# How to interpret: $f(e^{2\pi i x})$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm very rusty on complex numbers, so I apologize if this is very trivial.

I've encountered a text that defined a function: $\Phi:=C_\mathbb{R}(S^1)\to C_{\mathbb{R},\text{periodic}}(\mathbb{R})$, which returns a continuous, periodic function $f:= \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ , such that: $\Phi(f)(x) = f(e^{2\pi i x})$.

What is the formula for $e^{2\pi i x}$, $x$ is a real number. If there's an example of how to understand this (with, say $x=\sqrt{2}$) that would be great. I looked at Euler's formula, but it seems to require only natural numbers (?).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$? Otherwise it makes no sense

Comment: $e^{2\pi i x}=\cos(2\pi x)+i\sin(2\pi x)$

Comment: I've fixed the definition of $\phi$ as per the text.

Comment: I think you must mean $\Phi(f): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the periodic function.

Comment: There is an abuse of notation. $f(e^{2\pi x})$ is supposed to be just $f(x)$ (which is unambiguous by periodicity).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you mind please explaining further? (this is the definition in the text, double checked, but would like to understand exactly what you mean so I can identify this sort of ambiguity myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understood what your notation means. Let $\mathcal{F}(A,B)$ denote the set of all functions with domain $A$ and target space $B$.

First of all, we can consider the periodization mapping $P: \mathcal{F}(S^1,\Bbb{R})\to \mathcal{F}_{\text{$1$-periodic}}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$, defined as
\begin{align}
P(f)(x):= f(e^{2\pi i x})
\end{align}
Here, $f\in \mathcal{F}(S^1,\Bbb{R})$ is a function with $S^1=\{z\in \Bbb{C}\,:\, |z|=1\}$ as the domain. $P(f):\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is the function whose value at the point $x\in\Bbb{R}$ is by definition equal to $f(e^{2\pi i x})$. Now this makes perfect sense since if $x\in\Bbb{R}$, then $e^{2\pi i x}\in S^1$, so we can plug it into $f$ to get an output $f(e^{2\pi i x})\in\Bbb{R}$. THe function $P(f)$ is $1$-periodic due to the periodicity of complex exponential (that's essentially one of the ways to define the number $\pi$): for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
P(f)(x+1)&:=f(e^{2\pi i (x+1)})=f(e^{2\pi i x}\cdot e^{2\pi i})=f(e^{2\pi i x})=P(f)(x).
\end{align}

Lastly, you can restrict yourself to continuous functions. We have the continuous functions $C(S^1,\Bbb{R})\subset \mathcal{F}(S^1,\Bbb{R})$ is a subspace, and the 1-period continuous functions $C_{\text{$1$-periodic}}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})\subset \mathcal{F}_{\text{$1$-periodic}}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$. And $P$ restricts to a mapping between these subspaces, and this is what you have called $\Phi:C(S^1,\Bbb{R})\to C_{\text{$1$-periodic}}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$.

---

**Basic facts about complex number:**

For any $x\in\Bbb{R}$, we have $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$; this is Euler's identity. This follows easily from the power series definitions for the exponential, sine, and cosine:
\begin{align}
e^z:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!},\quad\text{and}\quad
\sin z:= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!},\quad
\text{and}\quad
\cos z:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n)!}.
\end{align}

Next, exponentials have the nice property that for all $z,w\in\Bbb{C}$, $e^{z+w}=e^z\cdot e^w$.

Finally, one can show that the mapping $x\mapsto e^{ix}$ maps $\Bbb{R}$ onto $S^1$, and that this mapping is periodic. The smallest positive period is a number which we call $2\pi$ (so this is one of the possible definitions of the number $\pi$).